# VungleSDK WebSocketException

Tags: unity-game-engine, win-universal-app, vungle-ads

I'm trying to use the `VungleSDK` plugin for Unity for a Windows 10 project. But I'm not getting it to work.

On their GitHub they mention that their SDK for UWP only works for Unity 5.**2**.x but I'm uncertain if they mean it doesn't work for Unity 5.**3**.x as I don't see why it shouldn't work with 5.3.x.

I'm recieving the following error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in VungleSDK.winmd
```

I've searched but couldn't find anything related to this. Also I couldn't try with Unity 5.2.X as it contain other bugs preventing me from building. :(

Anyone managed to build from Unity 5.3.x, if yes, did you do anything special?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is in doubt, the Vungle SDK plugin for Unity will also work in Unity 5.3.x.

It seems that the exception was thrown because there were (maybe) something wrong on their servers. How do I know? It works today without any changes to the code (some error code next time Vungle, pleeeease?).